# regular expression with or case

Tags: regex

I'm trying to compute a regex for this scenario:

the ID must start with the letter 'M' and ends with 3 digits, but triple zeros are not allowed.

I've tried

```
M(00[1-9])
```

But this only works on blocking triple zeros, how can I cater for the other digits?

Comment: Something like this M([0-9]{2}[1-9])

Comment: @Gunner But if the first two digits aren't 0s, the last one could be a 0, so that pattern wouldn't work.

Comment: Negative lookahead for triple zero.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You are right, I did not consider that. Sorry.

Comment: @NewbieCoder you want to block `M111`, `M222`...`M999` also?

Comment: @Gurman, nope. Only for triple zeros

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is probably with a negative lookahead:

```
M(?!0{3})\d{3}
```

[[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Efgy2O/4)]

This matches literal `M`, checks that the next thing is not triple zero, then  matches three digits.

If you want to block a specific set of digits, you can modify your lookahead to check for specific repeated digits (0, 2 5, 6 here):

```
M(?!([0256])\1{2})\d{3}
```

[[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Efgy2O/5)]

To check for all triple digits, replace `[0256]` with `\d`. This regex makes the lookahead check for one digit, then test if it is repeated twice using a backreference.

A less redundant way might be to put the capture group outside the lookahead:

```
M(\d)(?!\1{2})\d{2}
```

[[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/Efgy2O/6)]

This version says to capture one digit, make sure it is not repeated two more times, then capture two more digits.

Comment: Thanks for posting, will delete mine.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Sorry, I'm on mobile but not with the app. Didn't even  realize there were other answers.

Comment: Thanks alot! Didn't know it would be that complicated. New to regex here.

Comment: @NewbieCoder. This is actually about as simple and straightforward as regex can get. I understand that the concept of lookahead and lookbehind are not immediately intuitive though.